# Python passing list to class and attempting to reference values at index

Tags: python

I am attempting to create a list with 5 students information listed, which is then passed to the Student class. It seems that I have been successful in doing this, but now I am unable to figure out how to access and modify any of the previously added values with the list.

```
class Student:

    def __init__(self, student_name, student_id, student_gpa, student_grade, student_time):
        self.student_name = student_name
        self.student_id = student_id
        self.student_gpa = student_gpa
        self.student_grade = student_grade
        self.student_time = student_time

student_list = []
for i in range(5):
    student_name = input("Please enter student's name: ")
    student_id = input("Please enter student's ID number: ")
    student_gpa = input("Please enter student's GPA: ")
    student_grade = input("Please enter student's expected grade: ")
    student_time = input("Please enter if student is a part or full time student: ")
    student_list.append(Student(student_name, student_id, student_gpa, student_grade, student_time))
```

How might I add the option to reference a Student's name and alter the grade from what was originally entered?

Comment: To access the students by name, it would probably better to use a dict, rather than a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a list of Student objects and the list is pretty small.So,you can loop through the list and find the student.
Here,the student id is an unique way of identifying the particular student.

```
def change_gpa(id):
     for student in student_list:
         if student.student_id == id:
            # Take input from the user of the changes to be made
            # Example gpa
            student.student_gpa = input('Enter new gpa')
            return
change_gpa(input('Enter the student id whose credentials have to be changed'))
```

Comment: You should break out of the loop once you find the student

Answer (score 1):

You ahve a list containing instances of the Student class, you can simply iterate over it, for example:

```
for student in student_list:
    if student.student_id == something:
        student.student_grade = whatever #it changes the value
```

or, if you know exactly which student you want to modify in the list you can do:

```
student_list[0].student_grade = whatever #assuming you want to modify the first student in the list
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 3:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, student_name, student_id, student_gpa, student_grade, student_time):
        self.student_name = student_name
        self.student_id = student_id
        self.student_gpa = student_gpa
        self.student_grade = student_grade
        self.student_time = student_time        

student_list = []
for i in range(3):
    student_name = input("Please enter student's name: ")
    student_id = input("Please enter student's ID number: ")
    student_gpa = 3.73
    student_grade = "B-"
    student_time = 2017
    '''
    student_gpa = input("Please enter student's GPA: ")
    student_grade = input("Please enter student's expected grade: ")
    student_time = input("Please enter if student is a part or full time student: ")
    '''
    student_list.append(Student(student_name, student_id, student_gpa, student_grade, student_time))

print("Origianl Information")
for student in student_list:
    print(student.student_id,student.student_name,student.student_gpa)

search_student = input("Enter a student name to change GPA: ")
for student in student_list:
    if student.student_name == search_student:
        student_gpa = input("Enter new GPA of "+search_student+": ")
        student.student_gpa = student_gpa

print("Updated Information")
for student in student_list:
    print(student.student_id,student.student_name,student.student_gpa)
```

Output:

```
Please enter student's name: Shovon
Please enter student's ID number: 2389
Please enter student's name: Aslam
Please enter student's ID number: 2383
Please enter student's name: Nafis
Please enter student's ID number: 56
Origianl Information
2389 Shovon 3.73
2383 Aslam 3.73
56 Nafis 3.73
Enter a student name to change GPA: Shovon
Enter new GPA of Shovon: 3.96
Updated Information
2389 Shovon 3.96
2383 Aslam 3.73
56 Nafis 3.73
```

N.B.: I have commented some of the lines for reducing the huge input. Uncomment those.